# How to avoid BAT FOR failure on non-ascii characters?

Tags: windows-7, cmd, windows-xp

How can this BAT file line:

FOR %%F in (Q:\Playlists*.m3u) do sed -e"s~^\~R:&~" > "R:%%~pnxF"

be recoded to avoid the observed failure on filenames containing non-ascii characters e.g. á?

Perhaps using short names.

Comment: "maybe move to the superuser site" Why so? This is about programming.

Answer (score 1):

```
FOR %%F in (Q:\Playlists*.m3u) do (
 sed -e"s~^\~R:&~" > "R:\junkname"
 ren "R:\junkname" "%%~nxF"
)
```

May suit. I can't test it since I don't have non-ASCII filename characters easily available.

(noting that `~p` should be resolved to `\`)

Answer (score 0):

Solution found - ~s :

FOR %%F in (Q:\Playlists*.m3u) do sed -e"s~^\~R:&~" -e"s~....$~.wma~" "%%~sF" > "R:%%~pnxF"

I see

> DIR /X  ... "If no short name is present, blanks are displayed 
>   in its place."

and I'm hoping ~s is safe from this.

This suggests so:

[image]

Anyone know for sure?

Comment: There is a bug in the `℅℅~sF` function, look [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?hl=en&fromgroups#!topic/alt.msdos.batch.nt/r7Aj4XkogbU).